# Looking for some better words other than "by chance"

Tags: phrase-request, vocabulary

I read some news about my friend being robbed on a local newspaper.

The newspaper was published a few weeks ago, but I read it two days ago.

I wanted to send my late regards to her, but I thought she would ask me how I knew it.
I was thinking to write this:

> "I saw you getting robbed on newspaper by chance"

But I don't want to use the phrase, by chance, because I think "by chance" relates to gambling and betting.

Thank you.

Comment: **by chance** doesn't necessarily refer to gambling. It can refer to any unplanned or random occurrence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could subtly say:

- *"I heard that you were robbed."*
- *"I came to know that you were robbed."*
- *"I read that you were robbed."*
- *"I came across the news that you were robbed."*
- *"I was informed that you had been robbed."*

To make it a little more subtle, and to show that you care, you could append something to make it seem more personal like "*..are you okay?*" to it.

If you want to stress on the '*chance*' part even then, maybe you should you try '**[incidentally](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=incidently&oq=incidently&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1552j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)**'

Answer (score 5):

> I **happened** to see|read in the newspaper that you were robbed.

**HAPPEN** + **to** + {verb}  presents something as an  unpremeditated act or chance event, or as a coincidental fact.

> I happened to meet him on the train platform.
>
> She happens to know your cousin.

[Some examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22happened%20to%20see%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) with the verb **see**.